# defining exponentially many constraint in MIP solver

Tags: optimization

As learned from one of the book on mixed integer programming. We know the state of the art solver for traveller sales man use exponentially many constraints. But the input of such constraints into a  MIP solver would need exponentially much time.. How is that practically achieved in a MIP solver especially Gurobi? Thank you:D

The main problem is that: to define my problem, it takes 170 seconds, while solving the problem only takes 17 seconds.......

Comment: Maybe the solver doesn't need all constraints listed explicitly?

Comment: ehm.....not sure... I remember it is said to be something like a separation oracle.....

Comment: and that TSP formulation is integral also...